# Trying to change column color of my datatable through frontend script

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have a code in the back that uses json data and creates table being filled with data. After it serializes it fills the datatable. I use DataTables, and I am using this code to change color of columns, but it does nothing.

```
    $(function () {
            //$('td').css('background-color','red');
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();
            table.api().columns().eq(0).css('background-color','red');
            table.draw();
   });
```

Outline is `<table><thead></thead><tbody><tr class='odd'><td></td></tbody><table>`

I tried using .ready() as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#example > tbody > tr > td').css('background-color','red');
 });
```

Comment: Your code (the second snippet), works fine as provided https://jsfiddle.net/jzuyeg91/ - make sure your second doc ready is after, or included within, the first.   Note that datables recreates the table on any/all changes so you should add this either within the datatables configuration (ideal) or on one of the callbacks datatables provides.

Comment: If you can provide a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* the issue (see [mcve]) we can look into your exact issue in more detail.  See the [datatables SO wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) for help on what's need in the snippet (or check the fiddle above)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it don't have a value in yout td cells, causing you not to see the change. Also ensure the `tr` tag is closed in your code.

```
$('tr').css('background-color', 'red')
```

```
<table>
  <thead>
    
  </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class='odd'>
      <td>
        Something
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Further, I don't see the need to use JS since you can easily color the table rows with CSS:

```
// or even
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
```